# Handler Stops after some time

Tags: android, handler

I my app I am using Handler which does its work after every 1 min , It in my MainActivity the problem is that after some time It stop working. This is Happening in samsung galaxy note gt n7000 but when I run same code in other non branded phone it works fine I am using Handler  as following what is wrong with it ?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                         //doing some Task
                 handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
}
```

Comment: It is hard to answer this question correctly without context, so bring one here.

Comment: i had same problem as handler gets stop if phone is goes to sleep or its gets locked.you may use alarmmanager its works even phone is in sleep mode.hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handler may stop working because of many reasons.

Two obvious are:

- process being killed
- CPU stopped doing anything because phone went sleep

Note that your code causes memory leak after Activity is destroyed.

Anyway use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for what you want to achieve.

**Edit:**

A fine (and fairly short) read about why `AlarmManager` is the correct way from CommonsWare: http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a Service.. ( Service with notifications won't be killed by an android os).
Some apps like Rounder and GloveBox are using notifications in order to prevent them to be killed by a system.

Comment: Service won't prevent CPU from getting too lazy to execute. ;)

Comment: however if you want your app to work even if device went to sleep mode, you got to use services, and better use them with notifications.